# Render to texture: Maximum number?

Tags: android, framebuffer, texture2d

I hava a class in an Android App that holds a byte array as data source for a texture. I use a Framebuffer to render some stuff onto that texture and then render the texture on the screen. This works perfectly.

However, I can do this with 151 textures only. Instance #152 generates this error:

```
:0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem: Error 1 returned
:0: ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Can't create render surface.
```

**Here is the code snippet (Constructor):**

```
// Texture image bytes
   imgBuf=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEXEL_X*TEXEL_Y*3);
   imgBuf.position(0);

// Fill the texture with an arbitrary color, so we see something
   byte col=(byte)(System.nanoTime()%255);
   for (int ii=0; ii<imgBuf.capacity(); ii+=3)
   {  imgBuf.put(col);
      imgBuf.put((byte)(col*3%255));
      imgBuf.put((byte)(col*7%255));
   }
   imgBuf.rewind();

// Generate the texture
   GLES20.glGenTextures(1,textureID,0);
   GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureID[0]);

   GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
    GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
    GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

   GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

   GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
    GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

// Associate a two-dimensional texture image with the byte buffer
   GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GLES20.GL_RGB,TEXEL_X,
    TEXEL_Y,0,GLES20.GL_RGB,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,imgBuf);

   GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);

// Get framebuffer for later rendering to this texture
   GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1,frameBufID,0);
```

**And here is the problem (Render to texture)**

If I leave out this part, displaying hundreds of such textures works well, but then I cannot render anyting onto the texture :( If I keep it, it works fine with 151 textures.

```
// Bind frame buffer and specify texture as color attachment
   GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBufID[0]);
   GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureID[0],0);

// Check status
   int status=GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
   Log.i(TAG,texNum+":"+status);

// Render some stuff on the texture
// ......
// (It does not matter. The status check fails even without rendering anything here)

   GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0);
   GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
```

I hope somebody can shed light upon this.
Thanks,
Ru

Comment: 151 FBOs sounds pretty high, what do you need so many for?

Comment: Its not 151 FBOs. I use just one (always the same) for offscreen rendering. A texture is are attached, render to texture done and detached. Then I proceed to the next texture, and so on. I am not aware of any memory leak because the textures exist also without the FBO, and without using the FBO there is no problem - but no offscreen rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably using a device with PowerVR SGX540 GPU, they have this problem on android. Not on iOS, so this seems like a driver issue despite what their support says on their forum:

http://forum.imgtec.com/discussion/3026/glcheckframebufferstatus-returns-gl-framebuffer-unsupported-when-creating-too-many-fbo

If you really need to have more than 152 textures rendered to then you have to read out the pixels with glReadPixels(), delete the texture and fbo, and create a new texture by providing the data to glTexImage2D